# Viewing recent activity in a GitHub project

Tags: github

How can I view recent activity on a GitHub project?

I can see [pulse](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse) (see this [example](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pulse) and noted in [this webapps question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43231/how-do-i-get-an-overview-of-recent-activity-for-a-github-repository)), but that separates out events by what kind of event they are.

Ideally, I would like to see all events listed in chronological order, so I can see what was the most recent event.

Comment: What kind of *events* do you refer to, exactly ? Because, the list of all commits can be of great help to see the activity on the project (but, I suspect that you are looking for something more specific!).

Comment: @perror when you say "all commits" do you mean all commits in any branch, or all commits in a single branch? Other activity includes pull requests and issues.

Comment: The "pulse" is the best you can get about Github project recent events.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Well, in your example it would be this [page](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commits/master)... But, I guess you know this already and this is not what you need. I think that the problem is that you did not describe enough what you want (I guess).